Cygwin Make (4.4.1) for windows - execute python file Permission denied
I updated my make for windows from 4.2.1 to 4.4.1 (got it from cygwin). Right now I am facing following issue after the update:
C:\>make build
C:\test.py
make: C:\test.py: Permission denied
make: *** [makefile:3: build] Error 127

I can solve this problem with several workarounds:

use the old make version
use cmd /C or python in my makefile in front of the path to the python file
putting "" around the path to the python file

In my build infrarstructure this always worked fine, and I am wondering if anyone has a clue why these workarounds are necessary now.
makefile:

    .PHONY: build
    build:
        C:\test.py


Note:
I checked the user and permissions but they seem fine and probably are not the problem.

I'm very surprised that you can successfully use backslashes in pathnames, in a version of make built with cygwin.  A cygwin-compiled make (as I understand it) expects POSIX-style paths and uses a POSIX shell, which will definitely not allow a backslash as a pathname separator.

You will probably need to write the command as py c:\\test.py or python c:\\test.py orpy c::/test.py or python c:/test.py. You might have to replace py with c:/Windows/py.exe. I would define PY=py eg and use $(PY) $(TEST_PY) in the makefile to make testing the combos easier. I would also verify I was actually using CYGWIN's make with a where make.
